# Reset branch on git commit hook

Tags: git, github, githooks

I have googled around but cannot find the right answer.

What I basically want is to be able to have a git hook on the client side (Developer Machines) that would not allow them to touch a branch.

Ex.

Master: I am able to lock master using gitlab to only Lead developers; However, I would like master to only be touched via a merge and never let anyone touch master directly. What I would like is a git hook that would not let them commit the changes they are making to master.

My idea would be to have a pre-commit hook that would do a

```
 git reset --hard
```

on master, if anyone tries to commit changes on master.

```
  #!/bin/sh

  if ref == 'refs/heads/master':
        print "=============================================="
        print "Error. You cannot Make Changes to Master      "
        print "=============================================="

        SOMEHOW RUN git reset --hard
```

would something like this work? and How could I run a git command?

Comment: I think a better approach would be to simply disallow pushes to `master` on your shared repository - allow them to mess around on `master` in their own repository as much as they want, but don't accept any changes to be propagated out of their playground.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null)" = "refs/heads/master" ]
then
    echo "Cannot make changes to master"
    exit 1
fi
exit 0
```

Exiting non-zero from a `pre-commit` hook aborts the commit. No need to delete all their changes because they forgot to switch branches so I omitted `git reset --hard`.

Comment: **git add -u**
====
**git commit -m 'test commit'**

.git/hooks/pre-commit: 2: [: refs/heads/master: unexpected operator
[master 8beee38] test commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rewrite IT Assessment .doc (66%)


This is the error message i received when adding your code to the pre-commit hook

Comment: .git/hooks/pre-commit: 2: [: refs/heads/master: unexpected operator
[master 8beee38] test commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 rewrite IT Assessment .doc (66%)

Comment: that is the error I got when entering a commit. I opened up my pre-commit hook and added your code but it does not seem to like it :(. I am sorry.